# function php to combine array

Tags: php, arrays

What function should I use to combine `array 0` with `array 1` based on `extref`. The combination of the array is true if the value `extref` is the same as `array 0` and `array 1`.

```
Array
([Transaction] => Array
        ([0] => Array //firts index array
                ([extref] => WVB4108-10002761
                    [Denominations] => Array
                        ([Denomination] => Array
                                ([0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [denomvalue] => 0.10
                                            [denomqty] => 5
                                            [denomcount] => 0.50
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [denomvalue] => 0.50
                                            [denomqty] => 2
                                            [denomcount] => 1.00
                                        )

                                ))))

            [1] => Array //second index array
                ([extref] => WVB4108-10002761
                    [Denominations] => Array
                        ([Denomination] => Array
                                (
                                    [denomvalue] => 1.00
                                    [denomqty] => 13
                                    [denomcount] => 13.00
                                )

                        ))
```

the result should look like as below :-

```
Array
([Transaction] => Array
        ([0] => Array
                ([extref] => WVB4108-10002761
                    [Denominations] => Array
                        ([Denomination] => Array
                                ([0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [denomvalue] => 0.10
                                            [denomqty] => 5
                                            [denomcount] => 0.50
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [denomvalue] => 0.50
                                            [denomqty] => 2
                                            [denomcount] => 1.00
                                        )

                                     [2] => Array
                                         (
                                             [denomvalue] => 1.00
                                             [denomqty] => 13
                                             [denomcount] => 13.00
                                         )

                                ))))
```

Comment: Can you show what the result should look like?

Comment: `if ($array['Transaction'][0]['extref'] == $array['Transaction'][1]['extref']) { $result = true; } else { $result = false; }`

Comment: Edt the question to show what you want, don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two `extref`, and use `array_merge` if they're the same.

```
if ($array['Transaction'][0]['extref'] == $array['Transaction'][1]['extref']) {
    $array['Transaction'][0]['Denominations']['Denomination'] = 
        array_merge($array['Transaction'][0]['Denominations']['Denomination'], $array['Transaction'][1]['Denominations']['Denomination']);
        unset($array['Transaction'][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = ....
    $documentation = [];
    foreach($array['Transaction'] as $transaction)
    {
        $extref = $transaction['extref'];
        if(!isset($documentation[$extref]))
            $documentation[$extref] = [];
        $documentation[$extref] = array_merge($documentation[$extref], $transaction['Documentations']['Documentation'] )
    }

    $o = [];
    foreach($documentation as $key => $value)
    {
        $o[]=array('extref' => $key, 'Documentations' => array('Documentation' => $value));
    }

    return array('Transaction' => $o);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://3v4l.org/Cp1O9)'s a way to achieve this with arbitrary transactions:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['extref'] == $b['extref'])
        return 0;
    return ($a['extref'] < $b['extref']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($arr['Transaction'], 'cmp');

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr['Transaction'])-1 ; $i++){
    if ($arr['Transaction'][$i]['extref'] == $arr['Transaction'][$i+1]['extref']){
        $arr['Transaction'][$i] = array_merge_recursive($arr['Transaction'][$i],array_splice($arr['Transaction'],$i+1,1)[0]);
        $arr['Transaction'][$i]['extref'] = reset($arr['Transaction'][$i]['extref']);
    }
}
```